# openjdk platform binary duplicate in task manager android 4.1.1

Tags: java, android

When I build my project the task manager duplicate openjdk platform binary
how can I resolve this problem?

[image: Screenshot of task manger in windows]

1

System specifications: 16 GB RAM, , i7, Dell , Win 10.

Comment: Maybe it is the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65482929/multiple-duplicate-openjdk-binaries-on-start-of-android-studios-gradle-sync-fai)? The [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65817865/13156480).

Comment: the answers not working for me

Comment: Please provide more info about your environment (PC/Mac/Linux), which IDE with version (if using. plugins, which version), and steps to duplicate the issue. Does Android Studio 4.1.2 resolve the issue?

Comment: [The Dev with No Name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13156480) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66280875) saying "Have you tried updating everything like the IDE, gradle or openjdk itself? Maybe even reinstalling openjdk could help. Are you sure it's only building the app, not running it in the background?"

Comment: How do you build your project? Could you please show the commandline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, Windows 10 Hotspot was the culprit, switched it off,, it worked and didn't duplicate

I tried many solutions, but surprisingly this worked,, and I really don't know why

some other people had similar openjdk memory issues
some had it fixed by switching off airplane mode in emulator !
some had it fixed by switching off windows firewall and/or antivirus !!
some restarted PC, some cleared cache and restarted the editor and removed .gradle folder,, and many many failed attempts

only turning hotspot off fixed it for me