# Multiple Duplicate Openjdk binaries on start of android studios/ gradle sync failed, 96% RAM

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

System specifications: 16 GB RAM, GTX 1050 8GB, i7 8th gen, HP OMEN 17T(2018), Win 10.
On opening android studios(Fresh download), multiple(80+) OpenJDK platform binary files(consume 100MB each) are opened during Gradle build(binaries can be seen running on task manager in the given image). These files take 97% of my system RAM, following which android studio crashes due to failed Gradle sync/unable to start Gradle daemon(unable to allocate memory for object heap).
These rogue OpenJDK files do not close even after I terminate android studios and continue consuming RAM.
Uninstalling and reinstalling android studios do not seem to help.

my normal RAM consumption is 20-27% and all other system processes run fine, I have McAfee antivirus on at all times.

[task manager at android studio runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSYpa.jpg)

Comment: There's been at least 2 other questions regarding OpenJDK, none of which currently have answers. The only reasonable answer at this point is, it's a bug. Has nothing to do with antiviruses, system configurations, or just one-off bugs: it's Android Studio being dumb. All you can do is wait for an update, or install an older version if it's way too disruptive

Comment: Hey @Zoe, 
I've noticed that these OpenJDK binaries do not generate in other Desktops (running the same version). is there any other way to build Gradle without having to use OpenJDK? as in tweaking the settings to overcome this bug?
Thanks!

Comment: Gradle itself builds on a JVM language, and you need OpenJDK to compile stuff. You might be able to switch to a different JDK version or variant (the JDK is open-source, so there's at least 3 common variants; Google "adoptopenjdk"), but you can't get around using Java

Answer (score 4):

I can't believe that this exact issue I've been facing for days was simply fixed by switching off the Hotspot in my windows 10

Don't ask me why or how I don't know,, it just fixed it,, in my case

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading gradle worked for me! just open project structure in Android Studio and choose gradle version as 6.0 and plugin version as 3.6.4.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with Gradle itself, seems like a bug(as @Zoe mentioned in the comments). A temporary solution is to start Gradle in offline mode. You can let it connect to the internet once the Gradle build is complete(Gradle daemon started successfully).

I tried adding other unrelated java files in the bin folder and found those binaries to be duplicated in my task manager along with OpenJDK, hope the Studio dev team fixes this soon.

Comment: Is this bug still there?